# How to check does a file imports from another file in Python

Tags: python, import

Suppose i have a project structure like this

```
src
└── app
    ├── main.py
    ├── db
    │   └── database.py
    ├── models
    │   ├── model_a.py
    │   └── model_b.py
    └── tests
        ├── test_x.py
        └── test_y.py
```

I want to check which file uses a **class** or a **function** from another file. I have a class called Test in main.py

```
class Test:
    pass
```

I used that class in `model_a`,

```
from ..main import Test
```

But in `model_b` i used

```
from ..main import Test
from ..db.database import Data
```

I want to to check which file uses another file, just like `tree` command, just a folder name is enough so i tried an old method but it was inefficient ,dirty and that was not something that i expect. The method  was i created a file in `src` named `check.py`, i imported all packages

```
from app.db import database
from app.models import model_a, model_b
from app.tests import test_x, test_y
from app import main 

print('__file__={0:<35} | __name__={1:<20} | __package__={2:<20}'.format(__file__,__name__,str(__package__)))
```

And i added this line in the bottom of all files

```
print('__file__={0:<35} | __name__={1:<20} | __package__={2:<20}'.format(__file__,__name__,str(__package__)))
```

So when i run `check.py` i get this result

```
__file__=/home/yagiz/Desktop/struct/src/app/main.py | __name__=app.main             | __package__=app                 
__file__=/home/yagiz/Desktop/struct/src/app/db/database.py | __name__=app.db.database      | __package__=app.db              
__file__=/home/yagiz/Desktop/struct/src/app/models/model_a.py | __name__=app.models.model_a   | __package__=app.models          
__file__=/home/yagiz/Desktop/struct/src/app/models/model_b.py | __name__=app.models.model_b   | __package__=app.models          
__file__=/home/yagiz/Desktop/struct/src/app/tests/test_x.py | __name__=app.tests.test_x     | __package__=app.tests           
__file__=/home/yagiz/Desktop/struct/src/app/tests/test_y.py | __name__=app.tests.test_y     | __package__=app.tests           
__file__=/home/yagiz/Desktop/struct/src/check.py | __name__=__main__             | __package__=None
```

**The result is dirty and doesn't meet my expectations is there a way to get a output like this?**

```
main.py = app/models/model_a, app/models/model_b   # These files imports something from main.py
models_b = None                                    # No file imports from models_b
```

### Update, i tried @Hessam Korki's suggestion **it doesn't works**.

I looked up the source code of [modulefinder](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/modulefinder.py) and i found it adds a badmodule in every import statement which is not useful for me.

Here is how did it go, first i created a function, also i created an another project structure.

```
src
├── empty.py
├── __init__.py
├── main.py
├── module_finder.py
├── other
│   └── other.py
├── test
│   └── some_app.py
└── this_imports.py
```

Here is the `module_finder.py` that contains my function

```
from modulefinder import ModuleFinder
file_names = ["this_imports.py", "main.py", "test/some_app.py", "other/other.py", "empty.py"]

def check_imports(file_names):
    finder = ModuleFinder()
    for file in file_names:
        finder.run_script(file)
        print("\n", file)
        for name, mod in finder.modules.items():
            print('%s: ' % name, end='')
            print(','.join(list(mod.globalnames.keys())[:3]))

            print('\n'.join(finder.badmodules.keys()))
```

Empty file is **empty**(as expected), in `main.py` i have

```
class Test:
    pass
```

In `this_imports.py` i only have

```
from src.main import Test
```

In `other/other.py` i have

```
from src.main import Test 
from src.test import DifferentTest
```

And for the last one in `test/some_app.py` i have

```
from src.main import Test

class DifferentTest:
    pass
```

So the result should be:

```
empty.py = None
main.py = None
other/other.py = src.main , src.test
test/some_app.py = src.main
this_imports.py = src.main
```

But the function gives a wrong result, here is the output:

```
 Filename:  this_imports.py
__main__: Test
src.main

 Filename:  main.py
__main__: Test,__module__,__qualname__
src.main

 Filename:  test/some_app.py
__main__: Test,__module__,__qualname__
src.main

 Filename:  other/other.py
__main__: Test,__module__,__qualname__
src.main
src.test

 Filename:  empty.py
__main__: Test,__module__,__qualname__
src.main
src.test
```

Comment: Why not use a simple grep with regex? `grep -rnw . -e "from\s\.*main\simport\sTest"`

Comment: @RamonMoraes i have no problem with finding import statements. My question is how to understand which file imports anything from another file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is to find import dependencies in your package modules. You can run a static analysis on your package directory and parse the import nodes in the syntax trees (`ast`), and build a dependency graph. Something like below:

```
import os
from ast import NodeVisitor, parse
import networkx as nx

class Dependency():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.base = os.path.basename(root)
        self.dependency = nx.DiGraph()
        self.visitor = NodeVisitor()
        self.visitor.visit_ImportFrom = self.visit_ImportFrom
        
        self.current_node = None
        self.dependency.add_node = self.base
        
    def visit_ImportFrom(self, node):
        self.dependency.add_edge(node.module, self.current_node)
        self.visitor.generic_visit(node)
        
    def run(self):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self.root):
            for file in files:
                full_path = os.path.join(root+os.sep, file)
                loc = full_path.split(self.root+os.sep)[1].replace(os.sep,'.')
                self.current_node = self.base+'.'+loc
                with open(full_path) as fp:
                    src = fp.read()
                    tree = parse(src)
                    self.visitor.generic_visit(tree)
                    
        dependency = {}
        for src, target in nx.dfs_edges(self.dependency):
            if src in dependency:
                dependency[src].add(target)
            else:
                dependency[src] = set([target])
                
        return dependency
```

For the root location of any package you want to map the import dependencies, you need to do the following then:

```
root = "path/to/your/src"
d = Dependency(root)
d.run()
```

This will return the dependency tree (as a dict). Note, we parsed only `ImportFrom`, you need to add `Import` to make it complete. Also, all imports are assumed absolute here (i.e. no `..` etc). If required, you can add that too (check the `level` field of the `ImportFrom` node to do that).

Comment: First of all thanks, secondly it throws an error on  `fp.read()` in line29 i tried open with it `rb` and encoding with other `utf-8` stuff but they didn't worked out. I would be grateful if you can take a look.

Comment: Also i changed the import statemens and used absolute import (src.main instead of ..main etc.)

Comment: I ran this on Python 3.7. What error do you get here? Btw, it is reading python source file, so should not read binary I suppose.

Comment: I'm getting `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 16: invalid continuation byte`

Comment: I see, it seems to be an unrelated error. Note the loop in the snippet assumes you have only `.py` files in your package directory. If that is not true, you can put a check to read only the python code files. Else, I suggest you try to do `open` and `read(fp)` the file directly (from a different script) to debug the issue.

Comment: I think you have `.pyc` files in there as well, add a check like below `_, ext = os.path.splitext(file)`, to get the file extension. If that is not `.py`, simply `continue` in the file read loop.

Comment: It worked like a charm when i delete the `__pycache__` thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I believe python's [Modulefinder](https://docs.python.org/3/library/modulefinder.html) will effectively solve your problem. There is a key named '__main__' in the Modulefinder().items() which holds the modules that were imported in a python file. After running the script through your project and storing the data in a way that suits your purpose, you should be good to go

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried your approach, it gave a wrong result, i updated the question, please check it out.

Comment: I checked your exact example on my machine. The reason you're getting wrong results is import errors, try running 'this_imports.py' directly; that can be solved by adding the 'src' path to your sys.path. However, you can find these with import errors in finder.badmodules dictionary right now(check the last line of each file that you printed your module report)

Comment: But why am i getting 2 different modules in `badmodules` even it's empty(see the result of `empty.py`)? also when i used `from main` instead of `from src.main` now the `badmodules` dict is empty so it's not returning any **imported modules** even if it imports successfully.

Comment: The reason “empty.py” returns badmodules has something to do with the content of your “\_\_init__.py”

Comment: When you run_script() your modules cleanly. There is a pair data in finder.modules dictionary for each module that has been imported to that file. The key is the name of the imported module and the value is the path of that module which I believe is the thing you’re looking for. Iterate through the dictionary and save the path of each one in a way that you are comfortable with.

Comment: Just asking for clarifying, how does `__init__.py`  affects to the other files since it's empty. also i looked [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/modulefinder.py) of modulefinder and  i found `_add_badmodule` has two statements if and else it adds badmodule in every condition when a file is imported. check it out.

Comment: @YagizcanDegirmenci once a module is in system you will see it when analyzing the next file, even if it's not imported by that file. Do you need this for an external check or you need it to run within the project? Why not just `greping imports`? And if you need it in python, do a `os.walk` before to get the list of all packages below `src`. Ping me if you want me to implement it in python or bash

Comment: @aerijman i need to check this externally, _Q: Why not just greping imports?_ : It's going to be a part of a library so it needs to be os independent(maybe subprocessing can help), also i think i didn't explained the question well, i need only file names and which file imports anything from another file. it so i only need imports to understand is it using a user-created-function-or-class i need to understand this, i don't need all the other imports from std lib or downloaded imports etc.

Comment: @YagizcanDegirmenci I understand, but if you store all filenames in a list then you only check for those imports. Also, I am not sure, but I believe that os.walk is independent of the operative system.

Comment: Oh that's a great idea, but as i remember `os.walk()` is slow, and this library going to used on deeply nested projects to understand how project works, kinda like getting project hierarchy, `os.walk()` calls `os.listdir()` on each directory it executes the stat() system call or `GetFileAttributes()` on each file to determine whether the entry is a directory or not, maybe i can go for a workaround with some bash thing like `find . -name "*.py" -exec grep import {} \;`

Comment: Check how slow os.walk is with time. I don't think it's going to be noticeable slower than any other method unless you keep millions of files in the path of a project, which is not adviced. Give it a try.  os.walk and then re.search for "^import" or "^from\ [A-Z,a-z]*\ import", etc...